# Can i move data extensions without breaking any processes?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, data, automation

I want to re-organize all the data extension in marketing cloud but in our business unit and parent business units, there are many processes running in the background like data automatons, journeys, content builder etc.

If I move the data extensions, is that going to break anything that is using path of any data extensions?

Answer (score 1):

Moving Data Extensions generally doesn't break anything, as long as you don't move it in or out of Shared Items. Moving it to Shared Items typically requires updating references to the DE in Query Activities.  Moving it to Shared would also break any Filters.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, it's fine to move around DE within the same business unit and it doesn't have any effect on the automation which use those DE's.I have tried it myself many times and never had any problems.